# Django does not send emails to admins on error 500

Tags: python, django, admin

I have following settings in my Django project

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'somemail@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'somemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'somemail@gmail.com'               #your acc and pass
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'somepassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

ADMINS = (('myusername', 'myemail@gmail.com'),)
```

But with this Django still does not send emails on `500 error` to admins. What is wrong here? It is said in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#admins) that I should enter a *full name* to `ADMINS` settings. Is that *full name* from default `User` model? What if I have empty those fields? More to that - there is no validation that fields should be unique and there might be another people with the same name that admin has?  
**P.S.** `send_mail()` from `python shell` works with those settings.

**UPDATE** My `Logging` settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Did you configure [AdminEmailHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler) in log settings ?

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG = True` set somewhere? Django only emails `ADMINS` when `DEBUG = False`.

Comment: @ FlipperPA yep, I know that, I have `DEBUG  = False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the LOGGING settings of settings.py add below block to *handlers*

```
            'mail_admins': {
              'level': 'ERROR',
              'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
```

**Update:**

Add following line to above block only if emails to be sent when DEBUG is False.

```
              'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
```

and with following settings in filters sections

```
        'filters': {
           'require_debug_false': {
              '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
           },
           'require_debug_true': {
              '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
           },
        },
```

**Update:**

Add `mail_admin` in `handlers` of  `loggers` as below

```
        'loggers': {
          'django': {
              'handlers': ['file', 'mail_admins'],
              'level': 'INFO',
              'propagate': True,
           },
         },
```

Comment: _require_debug_false_ is optional, if you don't want emails to be sent during DEBUG is True.

Comment: yep actually my project does not start with that option. what is that?

Comment: DEBUG should be set to True only when you are running django locally or during development. In production environments is strongly advised to set Debug to False.

Comment: I know that, I am asking about that my project fails to start with error: `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins': Unable to add filter 'require_debug_false': 'require_debug_false'` now. And I have `DEBUG = False` at that moment.

Comment: remove the _filters_ line altogether

Comment: already done, it started without that. will play around that, thank you.

Comment: finally I have tested your advise and that does not work :/ I still does not get emails on 500 error. (But I get emails, for example, on password reset, so it works). May be that is wrong ADMIN configuration? I provided there a name of superuser. Can it be admin automatically?

Comment: You have to add __mail_admins__ in any of handlers of loggers