# Django is not sending email to admins on error 500 (but email settings do work with send_mail!)

Tags: django

I know, there are plenty of similar questions about this, but none of them helped. When I set the `EMAIL_BACKEND` to `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`, I do see the email when I trigger a 500. When I set `EMAIL_BACKEND` to `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`, I don't receive the email.. but email manually sent using the `send_mail` function gets delivered just fine, so the email settings do work. I just don't understand this.

```py
DEBUG = False

EMAIL_BACKEND = env("EMAIL_BACKEND")
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "apikey"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env("SENDGRID_API_KEY")
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

SERVER_EMAIL = "{my email}"

ADMINS = [
    ("Kevin Renskers", "{my email}"),
]

MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

I don't have any custom `LOGGING` set, and like I said with `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` I do see the email in my console.

So how can it be that I can send email using `send_mail`, yet errors are not sent to me using the exact same email settings? I've looked in my sendgrid account activity, and yeah they are not sent at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django does not send emails to admins on error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408486/django-does-not-send-emails-to-admins-on-error-500)

Comment: I don't think so, as all my settings seem correct and since I have not overwritten the default LOGGING setting, and the default includes the `mail_admins` logic, it should just work, right?

Comment: So what happens if you explicitly call`mail__admins` just to test that?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Got a clear error when I did that: "The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved." Fix was to change the SERVER_EMAIL setting to another email address.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @michjnich for the suggestion to try to call [mail-admins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#mail-admins) manually. When I did I got a clear error:

`The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved.`

Turns out I needed to change `SERVER_EMAIL` to another email address as configured in Sendgrid. The reason why my manual `send_mail` call worked fine, is because I gave it the correct from address there.